# content of a table as columns in the result

Tags: sql

Can the operation shown in the following image be achieved elegantly in pure SQL and **without hardcoding** names into the statement?

[image: content of a table as columns in the result]

Tables A, B and C are given. The one on the right is the result I would like to get.

The following statement

```
SELECT name, val_name, val
FROM A, B, C
WHERE a_id = A.id
  and b_id = B.id
```

returns the correct information but not in the form I would like:

```
foo|goos|6
foo|blobs|7
bar|goos|8
baz|blobs|9
```

Comment: The result doesn't make direct sense from the input. Do you know how it is generated?

Comment: @yazanpro: Thanks for the remark. I do not know how the result is generated, because it is what I would like to have. If I knew how to get it, I would not ask. ;-) I added some explanatory SQL to my question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using *conditional aggregates*:

```
SELECT A.NAME, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN B.VAL_NAME = 'GOOS' THEN C.VAL END) AS GOOS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN B.VAL_NAME = 'BLOBS' THEN C.VAL END) AS BLOBS
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.A_ID
LEFT JOIN B ON C.B_ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.NAME
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28145/1)

Demo above is in MySQL. It should also work in most RDBMSs as this is ANSI standard SQL.

The solution clearly assumes that `VAL_NAME` values are already known by the time you write the query.

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice. And I'm sorry, I should have mentioned, that B can have many rows and I don't want to hardcode all val_names into the statement.

Comment: Then only option is to use dynamic SQL which is highly platform dependent I'm afraid.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I will then just use my initial statement to get the data and my calling programming language to reorder it.

Answer (score 1):

Prep the sample data:

```
  create table a (
     id          number,
     name        varchar2(10)
     )
  /

  create table b (
     id          number,
     val_name    varchar2(10)
     )
  /

  create table c (
     id          number,
     a_id        number,
     b_id        number,
     val         number
     )
  /

  insert into a values ( 1, 'FOO' );
  insert into a values ( 2, 'BAR' );
  insert into a values ( 3, 'BAZ' );
  insert into a values ( 4, 'QUX' );

  insert into b values ( 1, 'GOOS' );
  insert into b values ( 2, 'BLOBS' );

  insert into c values ( 1, 1, 1, 6 );
  insert into c values ( 2, 1, 2, 7 );
  insert into c values ( 3, 2, 1, 8 );
  insert into c values ( 4, 3, 2, 9 );

  commit;
```

Try this query:

```
select distinct a.name, 
      first_value(case when b_goo.val_name is not null then c.val else null end) over (partition by a.name order by b_goo.val_name nulls last ) goos,
      first_value(case when b_blob.val_name is not null then c.val else null end) over (partition by a.name order by b_blob.val_name nulls last ) blobs
   from a
      left outer join c
      on c.a_id = a.id
      left outer join b  b_goo
      on b_goo.id = c.b_id
         and b_goo.val_name = 'GOOS'
      left outer join b  b_blob
      on b_blob.id = c.b_id
         and b_blob.val_name = 'BLOBS'
/
```

Results:

```
  NAME             GOOS      BLOBS
  ---------- ---------- ----------
  QUX
  BAR                 8
  FOO                 6          7
  BAZ                            9
```

[edit] sorry, you wanted to show the ids, not the names, fixed that here[/edit]

So I just do some outer joins first, using 2 "copies" of your table B .. so I can have a GOO in 1 column and BLOBs in another.
Then I use FIRST_VALUE analytic function to pick out the first non-null value which helps collapse the duplicate rows ..
DISTINCT helps with that as well.

I did this in Oracle, however, it should work as is in other RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking solely of MS SQL Server, the answer (to the question of "can it be done *elegantly*") is No.

After joining the three tables, you would have to pivot the contents of `B.VAL_NAME`. This can only be done (in T-SQL) if you know the names of the values being "pivoted out" beforehand (which I am *assuming* you do not--otherwise, you wouldn't be storing them as explicit values in table B). As you do not know the names of the columns until run time, you would have to build the query *at* run time, using dynamic SQL. It works, but all told this kind of solution--of which I have written far too many instances of--is anything but "elegant".

If the resulting column names are known beforehand, @Dittos' solution will work, and you also wouldn't have to mess with inelegant pivot statements.

Comment: Here's a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555968/dynamic-sql-server-2005-pivot/7556220#7556220 to a previous answer to a similar question. It does an unpivot, but the logic is pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select 
    a.name,
    sum(case when d.valname = 'goods' then d.val 
             else 0 end) as goods,
    sum(case when d.valname = 'blobs' then d.val 
             else 0 end) as blobs
from a
left join (
    select c.aid, c.val, b.valname
    from c
    join b
    on c.bid = b.id
) d
on d.aid = a.id
group by a.name
```